# Parsing RSS in Python

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

I am trying to parse rss feed using python.

The rss feed has the format:

```
 <rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
      <channel>
                <title>Yahoo! News - Latest News & Headlines</title>
                <link>http://news.yahoo.com/</link>
                <description>...</description>
                <language>en-US</language>
                <copyright>Copyright (c) 2013 Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved</copyright>
                <pubDate>Thu, 30 May 2013 21:14:41 -0400</pubDate>
                <ttl>5</ttl>
                <image>...</image>
                <item>...</item>
                <item>...</item>
                <item>...</item>
      </channel>
 </rss>
```

I need to extract some details of the `<items>`.

Using `print feed['channel']['title']` etc I can get details of those blocks occurring only once. How do I extract details of the items? `feed['channel']entries[0]` or `feed['channel']['items[0]]` etc do not seem to work.

Comment: I assume you are using some sort of XML or RSS parsing library for this?

Comment: I am using the feedparser library

Comment: Is this what you need? http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/common-rss-elements.html#accessing-common-channel-elements "The items are available in d.entries, which is a list."

Answer (score 1):

```
feed.entries[doc_iter]['title']
```

Seems to work.
The `doc_iter` mentions the ith item.